# Replace specific values in openpyxl

Tags: python-2.7, csv, openxls

I have a excel file that looks like this:

```
   1984    1      1
   1985    1      1
```

I want to change all of the values in column 2 to 0 but I am not sure how to loop through rows.

I have tried:

```
import openpyxl

wb=openpyxl.load_workbook(r'C:\file.xlsx')
ws=wb['Sheet1']
for row in ws:
     row = [x.replace('1', '0') for x in row]
```

but that must not be how you loop through rows.

my desired out put is:

```
1984 0 1
1985 0 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
import openpyxl
excelFile = openpyxl.load_workbook('file.xlsx')
sheet1 = excelFile.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
currentRow = 1
for eachRow in sheet1.iter_rows():
    sheet1.cell(row=currentRow, column=2).value = "0"
    currentRow += 1
excelFile.save('file.xlsx')
```

Updates 2nd column to all zeros.